# how select two table in one query in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i wanna create some query like this in sequelize module i nod js.
can you help me for this??

SQL query:

```
SELECT subcategories.name as 'sub', categories.name as 'cat' FROM test.subcategories, test.categories;
```

thank you!

Comment: you made any schema or association for this ? if you have than please edit this i'll share you sequelize query for that .

Comment: thank you so much, i solved this problem with another way!

Comment: my associations are had mistake. i fixed that and solved!

Comment: @ZerOne5 okay :)